# Log in returns blank for incorrect password?

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I have been using a tutorial for a registration and log in page. Everything is perfect except when a user inputs an incorrect password.

If no password is entered then the stated error is displayed fine.

If the correct password is entered it logs them in.

If the incorrect password is entered it goes to a blank page?!

I want an incorrect password to display a message just like when the wrong username is entered. I've included my entire `login.php` code:

```
include('db.php');

if(!isset($_POST['login'])) {
    include('form.php');
} else {

    if(isset($_POST['user'])&&$_POST['user']==""||!isset($_POST['user'])) {
        $error[] = "Username Field can't be left blank";
        $usererror = "1";
    }

    if(!isset($usererror)) {
        $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$user'";
        if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql))=="0") {
            $error[] = "Can't find a user with this username";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['pass'])&&$_POST['pass']==""||!isset($_POST['pass'])) {
        $error[] = "password Field can't be left blank";
    }

    if(isset($error)) {
        if(is_array($error)) {
            echo "<div class=\"error\"><span>please check the errors and refill the form<span><br/>";
            foreach ($error as $ers) {
                echo "<span>".$ers."</span><br/>";
            }
            echo "</div>";
            include('form.php');
        }
    }

    if(!isset($error)) {
        $suser=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
        $spass=md5($_POST['pass']);//for secure passwords
        $find = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '$suser' AND password = '$spass'";
        if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($find))=="1"or die(mysql_error())) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $suser;
            header("Location: loggedin.php");
        } else {
            echo "<div class=\"warning\"><span>Some Error occured durring processing your data</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP mySQL Password issue with extra characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533356/php-mysql-password-issue-with-extra-characters)

Answer (score 2):

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($find))=="1"or die(mysql_error())){
```

If wrong password is entered, `mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($find))` is 0 so it results in `die(mysql_error())`. But since there is no `mysql_error()`, you see a blank page.

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query($find) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    // proceed
} else {
    // authentication failed
}
```

EDIT: This is just for illustration purpose only. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) when dealing with MySQL.

Comment: Hi Antony. Where would I implement this? Do I need to remove some of the code first. Thanks for your help, I'm new to PHP, have worked out some tweaks but...

Comment: @user1325308 You can replace the line of code I cited with the first 2 lines of my code and see if it works.

Comment: This is great progress.Thank you. The error it produces appears on a seperate page though. Ideally I wanted it to be produced on the same page just like "Can't find a user with this username" does. Is this possible? Is there not a replica of the username check that I can apply just for the password?

Comment: @user1325308 You can have the a single login.php that does the login check and display login textfields. From there you can check if the password is incorrect, and if so display a warning message above the form. You can use something like `if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 1) {$wrong_password = true;}`. Then place this above your form `<?php if ($wrong_password) { echo "You have entered a wrong password."; } ?>`.

Comment: Using your code I've managed to create the following which works with the current error reporting. However, it now says the password is incorrect even if its not... Any ideas? Thanks for your help again.           
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql))=="1") {$wrong_pass = true;}
{
$error[] = "Password is incorrect"; 
}
}

Comment: @user1325308 Note: `!=` (not equal to) vs. `==` (equal to). Use `if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql))!="1")`

Comment: Well spotted, sorry. I've made the change but it now gives me - Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in....

Comment: @user1325308 What does `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())` tell you? You have something wrong with your query.

Answer (score 0):

The code is little bit confusing for me, consider using this code.

```
<?php

include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
     $password = md5($_POST['pass']);

     if(empty($username) || empty($password)) {
          echo "Empty username or password.";
     } else {
          mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user` = '$user' AND `password.md5` = '$password'");
          if(mysql_num_rows() == 1) {
               // login successfull 
               session_start();
               $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
               header("Location: loggedin.php");
          } else {
               echo "Invalid username or password.";
          }
     }
} else {
     include  ('form.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. However there is a syntax error on line '$result = ... Are you able to amend please?

Comment: @user1325308, my code doesn't contain $result var. Check again.

Comment: @user1325308, OK my mistake, I put one extra semicolon at end. Check my edited answer.